# replace values in list depending on value of current item and next item

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to use the Python code below to output a new list. The output of print (words) should be `['my','name','is','michael','apples','i','like','cars']`.

Right now, `print (words)` outputs only `['cars']`. What am I missing here?

```
a = 'my name is michael and i like cars'
b = a.split()
words = None
for i, j in enumerate(b):
    words = []
    if j == "and" and b[i+1][0] == "i":
        words.append("apples")
    else:
        words.append(j)
print (words)
```

Comment: You have `words = []` in the loop body, clearing it with every iteration. Take it out of there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `words` outside the loop, you only see the last word because you keep setting words equal to an empty list each iteration:

```
words = [] # outside the loop
for i, j in enumerate(b):
```

If `and` happens to be the last word you will also get an `IndexError`.
You can set the start index to `1` in enumerate then you don't need to +1 and will avoid any potential error indexing:

```
words = []
for i, j in enumerate(b, 1):
    if j == "and" and b[i][0] == "i":
```

You can put it all in a list comprehension:

```
a = 'my name is michael and i like cars'
b = a.split()
words = ["apples" if wrd == "and" and b[i][0] == "i" else wrd for i, wrd in enumerate(b,1)]
print(words)
['my', 'name', 'is', 'michael', 'apples', 'like', 'cars']
```

You can also avoid indexing using `iter` and `next`:

```
a = 'my name is michael and i like cars'
it = iter(a.split())
words = ["apples" if wrd == "and" and next(it," ")[0] == "i" else wrd for wrd in it ]
print(words)
['my', 'name', 'is', 'michael', 'apples', 'like', 'cars']
```

Comment: Thanks for giving such a great & lengthy answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in your loop.
Every time you iterate, you reset `words` to `[]`

Set the list to `[]` outside of the for loop, like so:

```
words = []
for i, j in enumerate(b):
    if j == "and" and b[i+1][0] == "i":
        words.append("apples")
    else:
        words.append(j)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

TigerhawkT3 is correct.  To fix your code, instead of initializing words to None, try initializing it as an empty array:

```
a = 'my name is michael and i like cars'
b = a.split()
words = []
for i, j in enumerate(b):
    if j == "and" and b[i+1][0] == "i":
        words.append("apples")
    else:
        words.append(j)
print (words)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
a = 'my name is michael and i like cars'
b = a.split()
words = []
for x in range(len(b)-1):
    if b[x] == "and" and b[x+1] == "i":
        words.append("apples")
    else:
        words.append(j)
print (words)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a more compact method.

I think it's more readable and easy to understand. You can refer as below:

This is your var I delcare response:

```
a = 'my name is michael and i like cars'
b = a.split()
words = []
for i, j in enumerate(b):
    if j == "and" and b[i+1][0] == "i":
        words.append("apples")
    else:
        words.append(j)
print (words)
```

Comment: this only works for a single and and will still error if and is the last word

Comment: index cannot work as it only finds the first occurrence try `a = 'my name is michael and i like cars and i like foo'`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I see what you say. I set try and except to avoid the error.

Comment: I mean you have to loop to find every and, if you have 10 and's in a sentence index will only find the first.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So it is. You remind me of the important detail.